# Как получить данные из другой модели?

Tags: python, django, django-model

Помогите сообразить.
Есть две модели в джанге.

**Пользователи**. С полями "код моб оператора" (981, 999 и т.д.) и "тег" (бухгалтерия, менеджеры и т.д.)

**Рассылка**. С такими же полями + доп полями для настройки рассылки.

Не могу сообразить как прокинуть список указанных полей из модели пользователей модель рассылки в админке.
Наследование это не то.

К примеру, сохраняем пользователя с кодом оператора "999" и тегом "Бухгалтер".
Идём в настройку рассылки и там в таком же поле выбираем из выпадающего списка заведённые ранее в пользователе код оператора "999" и тег "Бухгалтер".

Т.е. в админке должен быть выпадающие списки с уже внесёнными кодами и тегами от объектов пользователя.

Comment: Вас интересует `ManyToMany` поле из модели Рассылки к молели Пользователи, и поиск с автодоплнением в админке (`autocomlete_fields`, `search_fields`)

Comment: Отлично. Тоже попробую.
Сейчас пробую вариант в админке сделать отдельное выпадающее поле, которое будет получать данные по нужным полям из модели пользователи в раздел рассылки в админке.